# Android RecyclerView messing up layout_weight

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-layout-weight

I have a pretty simple `RecyclerView` within a `DialogFragment`
A single-line item is supposed to show an image, first and last name and some numbers. They are laid out with the help of layout_weight to equally share the available space.

For some reason, some of the items randomly seem to calculate the layout_weight wrong.

Note that in the editor preview, and **after** scrolling the problematic item out of view, the problem is fixed and the layout returns to normal.

As you can see in the image, in the first item (it's not always (just) the first) the image gets way too much space.

[image: problem]

My layout is as follows;

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/dodger_blue"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_face"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/et_first_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/et_surname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/et_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/et_place"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="center|end"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my adapter;
https://gist.github.com/StefanDeBruijn/f032eac6619ac1b8420e352b883ea4dd

Comment: Are you passing the parent `ViewGroup` in the `inflate()` call in your `Adapter`?

Comment: Yes I do, gist added of my entire adapter

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is happening because of the large image being set in the image view. As you have set the height of the image as match_parent. To maintain the aspect ratio it is also expanding across the width.

Probably you should try adding this property to the  in your xml file and fixing the height of the image.

android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_height=100dp

Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: The same image is being used in all items though, its an image that's saved in the drawables. I've tried scaleType, but that didn't solve it  and it doesn't explain why it only happens to a few items, until they've been scrolled out of sight